# Getting "Invalid User Name or Password" error after moving Magento 1.9 to new server

Tags: magento, migration, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I moved Magento website from old to the new server using the following steps:

```
1. Export database and Search & Replace old domain URL in the editor.
2. Zip all Magento root files and upload on the new server using FTP.
3. Change the database name and user information in the app/etc/local.xml file.
```

Now website frontend working perfectly fine on the new server and I can also access the admin login page but my login credentials are not working.

Login credentials working fine on the old server but getting **"Invalid User Name or Password"** error on the new server.

I removed cache files from var/cache folder but still no luck.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot yet comment. Two things I can think of:

- The cookie domain not being set to the appropriate value.
- Using a different crypt value in local.xml

You can also try to set a new admin password directly in the database (you should backup the old value). Admin users are stored in `admin_user`. Magento 1.x saves the password as MD5 hashes, so you should be able to set a new password with `md5(PASSWORD)`.

Comment: I set both values but still no luck.

Comment: I have added a method with which you could try to set a new admin password.

Comment: Thanks, @nebulon42 I change the password in the database and remove cache files from var/cache folder and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

there was no admin_user in the database with my mail adres connected to. So i changed the mail adress in the database from on of the current admin_users through phpmyadmin. and then pressed "forgot my password" and filled in the new mailadres. Then i got a reset password in my mailbox. and it worked.